# Remove extra zeros from a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I know the ways to remove leading zeros from string:

```
'000100'.replace(/^0+/, '')
```

But if a float like string (e.g. '00100.2300' or '00100'), how to remove all extra zeros from it?

```
'00100.2300' => '100.23'  
'00100' => '100'  
'00100.0023' => '100.0023'
'100.00' => '100.' or '100' will better
'-100.002300' => '-100.0023'
'0.50' => '0.5'
```

Assume the string:

- Only contains numbers or dot or negative symbol '-', no characters and others.
- The decimal point doesn't appear first in the string. And up to one.
- The negative symbol '-' will appear in normal position. And no extra zeros before and after the '-'.
- The float represented by the string may be larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`
- Both positive and negative float are possible.

A function used to filter extra zeros may be releatively easy and more steps also.

And a regexp will be simpler.

Comment: is it possible the string contains characters and not only numbers?

Comment: Use this  : '00100.2300' .replace(/^0*/, ' ')

Comment: YourString.replace("0", ""); didn't test it but might work

Comment: Try `^0+|(\..*?)0+$` and replace with `$1`. Check here https://regex101.com/r/U2dwtd/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It occurs to me you can do a *single* find and replace to accomplish
everything.

With this, you match the entire *valid* number at a time, enabling you to
fix multiple numbers in a single string, if done globally.
Also works the same if your string contains a single number.

Find `(?:(-)(?![0.]+(?![\d.]))|-)?\d*?([1-9]\d*|0)(?:(?:(\.\d*[1-9])|\.)\d*)?(?![\d.])`
Replace `$1$2$3`

JS demo:  https://regex101.com/r/H44t6z/1

Readable / Info version

```
 # Add behind boundary check here
 # -----------------
 (?:
      ( - )                         # (1), Preserve sign -
      (?!                           # Only if not a zero value ahead
           [0.]+ 
           (?! [\d.] )
      )
   |                              # or
      -                             # Match sign, but dump it
 )?
 \d*?                          # Dump leading 0's
 (                             # (2 start), Preserve whole number 
      [1-9]                         # First non-0 number
      \d*                           # Any number
   |                              # or
      0                             # Just last 0 before decimal
 )                             # (2 end)
 (?:                           # Optional fraction part
      (?:                           # -------------
           (                             # (3 start), Preserve decimal and fraction
                \.                            # Decimal
                \d*                           # Any number
                [1-9]                         # Last non-0 number
           )                             # (3 end)
        |                              # or
           \.                            # Match decimal, but dump it
      )                             # -------------
      \d*                           # Dump trailing 0's
 )?
 (?! [\d.] )                   # No digits or dot ahead
```

Comment: Nice! How could you write so complex regex? It's too hard for me.

Comment: Thanks! I need to validate an html decimal input but I need to maintain the precision bigger than float could store. This allows me to store the number as string and send it straight to the backend where the actual calculation will be performed.

Answer (score 5):

Regex:

```
^0+(?!\.)|(?:\.|(\..*?))0+$
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/TfYB7A/1)

Breakdown:

- `^0+(?!\.)` Match leading zeros that don't meet a decimal point
- `|` Or
- `(?:` Start of non-capturing group

  - `\.` Match a decimal point
  - `|` Or
  - `(\..*?)` Capture a decimal point preceding digits
- `)` End of NCG
- `0*$` Match trailing zeros

JS code:

```js
var str = `00100.2300
00100
00100.0023
100.00
100.
00.50
0.5`;

console.log(
  str.replace(/^0+(?!\.)|(?:\.|(\..*?))0+$/gm, '$1')
)
```

Comment: I'm sorry. Really there have many examples in vary situations that I can't show them all. Just output the **normal number** by taking the above assumption .

Comment: @revo Good job!

Answer (score 1):

Something you can try is a native method:

```
parseFloat("000100.2300")
```

Then you can convert it back to the string with whatever method you want.

Comment: It can't works when a large float that bigger than 2^53 - 1. And process large float is the main purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `^0+` to capture leading zeros and `(\.\d*[1-9])(0+)$` to capture trailing zeros. So your regex should be: `/^0+|(\.\d*[1-9])(0+)$/g`

```js
var res = '00100.2300'.replace(/^0+|(\.\d*[1-9])(0+)$/g, '$1');
console.log(res);
var res2 = '100'.replace(/^0+|(\.\d*[1-9])(0+)$/g, '$1');
console.log(res2);
```

Comment: what about if the op passed the string 100

Comment: See my answer about `100`

Comment: '100.00'.replace(/^0+|(\.\d*[1-9])(0+)$/g, '$1') => '100.00'

Comment: If it were me (OP), I'd truncate trailing '###`.000`' decimal if also followed by all zero's. I'd also truncate the decimal if no numbers past it. `/^0+|(\.\d*[1-9])(0+)$|\.0*$/`

Answer (score 0):

This answer solve task even if string `100` is passed:

```
'00100.002300'.replace(/^0+|(\.0*\d+[^0]+)0+$/g, '$1')
```

> 100.0023

```
'00100'.replace(/^0+|(\.0*\d+[^0]+)0+$/g, '$1')
```

> 100

Answer (score 0):

It might be an idea to use JS type coercion here.

```js
var trim = s => +s+'',
    strs = ['00100.2300','00100','00100.0023','100.0023'],
    res  = strs.map(trim);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Notice that the value can be larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`

Answer (score 0):

I had float numbers in a string type and for data comparison from two different sources, I just needed to trim the trailing zeroes from numbers.

Using a regex seemed more prone for errors to me. Using a simple while loop checking whether the last character was a zero or not seemed like a sufficient check for me for a one-off script.

```
// Conversion example: "2.450" to "2.45"
// "3.200" to "3.2"
    function removeTrailingZero(percentage) {
      let ret = percentage;
    
      while (ret.charAt(ret.length - 1) === '0' || ret.charAt(ret.length - 1) === '.') {
        ret = ret.slice(0, -1);
      }
      return ret;
    }
```